# Spearman's Rank Correlation over spatial domain

Tags: python, geospatial, correlation, netcdf, python-xarray

I would like to calculate the Spearman's Rank correlation between two precipitation datasets (netcdf files opened using xarray), over the domain of Africa, over time, for each season and plot the correlations spatially. I found the following functions work, but the correlation calculated is Pearson's and I would like Spearman's.

```
def covariance(x, y, dims=None):
    return xr.dot(x - x.mean(dims), y - y.mean(dims), dims=dims) / x.count(dims)

def corrrelation(x, y, dims=None):
    return covariance(x, y, dims) / (x.std(dims) * y.std(dims))

ds2_djf_cor = corrrelation(da2_sum_season.sel(time=da2_sum_season.time.dt.month.isin([12])),
                           da1_sum_season.sel(time=da1_sum_season.time.dt.month.isin([12])), dims='time')
```

Anybody know how I could do this by either adjusting the above functions or starting from scratch?

Here is what the data looks like (it has been resampled to give seasonal totals):
da1_sum_season

```
<xarray.DataArray 'pre' (time: 148, lat: 162, lon: 162)>
array([[[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        ...,
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 137.2      ,
         142.3      , 143.9      ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 143.7      ,
         148.5      , 147.2      ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 146.1      ,
         150.2      , 154.70001  ]],

       [[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
...
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  26.900002 ,
          26.400002 ,  21.900002 ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  33.2      ,
          28.2      ,  26.7      ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  31.       ,
          31.400002 ,  25.800001 ]],

       [[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        ...,
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  35.       ,
          33.600002 ,  37.5      ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  36.6      ,
          37.4      ,  35.5      ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  36.       ,
          36.2      ,  34.4      ]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1981-03-01 1981-06-01 ... 2017-12-01
  * lon      (lon) float64 -20.25 -19.75 -19.25 -18.75 ... 59.25 59.75 60.25
  * lat      (lat) float64 -40.25 -39.75 -39.25 -38.75 ... 39.25 39.75 40.25
```

da2_sum_season

```
<xarray.DataArray 'precip' (time: 148, lat: 162, lon: 162)>
array([[[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        ...,
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 117.96996  ,
         137.49915  , 149.82387  ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 102.017044 ,
         128.21773  , 149.24342  ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 115.326996 ,
         114.31691  , 124.208435 ]],

       [[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
...
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  17.362268 ,
          17.088856 ,  15.534197 ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  20.717667 ,
          18.122211 ,  16.771612 ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  20.810205 ,
          20.894186 ,  19.719692 ]],

       [[        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,         nan,
                 nan,         nan],
        ...,
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  30.264874 ,
          29.965853 ,  29.489614 ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  31.865303 ,
          30.22337  ,  29.885433 ],
        [        nan,         nan,         nan, ...,  29.05289  ,
          31.94003  ,  29.72091  ]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1981-03-01 1981-06-01 ... 2017-12-01
  * lon      (lon) float64 -20.25 -19.75 -19.25 -18.75 ... 59.25 59.75 60.25
  * lat      (lat) float64 -40.25 -39.75 -39.25 -38.75 ... 39.25 39.75 40.25
```

Comment: I note that you wanted to do this "from scratch", however `xskillscore` package has such a function: 
https://xskillscore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/xskillscore.spearman_r.html

Comment: @RobertDavy thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. I was only suggesting "starting from scratch" if there wasn't an alternative/out of necessity.

Comment: @RobertDavy sorry another question, when using the xskillscore_spearman_r there are large patches on the output that are white (i.e. missing). Do you know what would be causing this? It's not possible that there is that much missing data in the original dataset. I think it is to do with tied ranks. How does this operation treat tied ranks?

Comment: Might be best to raise an issue on their github if you believe there is one.
If you delve into the code, it performs the spearman correlation by calling `bottleneck.nanrankdata` on each time series, then performing the pearson correlation of those two. I suppose if you had time series of all zeros ( not uncommon for precip ?) it could produce some strange results.

Comment: Thanks very much, I think it is a time series of zeros that is causing the problem.